# revalidate a form programmatically

Tags: angular

I have a simple form with controls. The value could be changed from various controls and uses a custom validator in which validation of control 1 is based on value of control 2. My issue now is if it is valid now but control 2 value changes, control 1 should be invalidated. Or if the current value of control 1 is valid against the newly selected value of control 2, control 1 should become valid.

So, I am thinking of re-validating the form entirely programmatically or perhaps control 1:

```
    this.rForm.controls['source'].setValidators(validNumberPerParent(this.selectedParent))

// i tried the form as well

this.rForm.markAsUntouched()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would remove the custom validator anyway (I assume this, because you are resetting the validator). But yes, assuming, since this is not a [mcve] Best would be if you were to create a stackblitz showcasing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I see clearly what you want to achieve, but maybe this can help if you validator is works as I assume:

```
this.selectedParent.valueChanges.subscribe(()-> this.rForm.get('source').markAsTouched());
```

Here I assume that the selectedParent is a control.
This will revalidate source if selectedParent changed